# Spring boot - autowire fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, autowired

I'm trying to fetch some properties from `application.properties` file ad my code is the following:

**Main Application class:**

```
package it.mysite;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MailSenderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MailSenderApplication.class, args);

        System.out.println("*****");
        for (String name : context.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        System.out.println("*****");
        new MySendService().sendReport();
    }
}
```

**My service class:**

```
package it.mysite.service;

@Service
public class MySendService {

    @Value("${mail.fc.to}")
    private String[] to;

    @Value("${mail.fc.subject}")
    private String subject;

    @Autowired ReportService reportEmailService;

    @Autowired MailProperties mailProperties;

    public void sendReport(){
        if(mailProperties.getTo().length > 0) {
    }
}
```

**Class where I fetch the properties:**

```
package it.mysite.properties;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("mail.fc")
public class MailProperties {

    private String[] to;

    public String[] getTo(){
        return to;
    }
}
```

**Config file:**

```
# Email config
mail.fc.to=my@mail.com
mail.fc.subject=My subject
```

All of the `@Autowired` properties are `null`, and also the `@Value` properties (I tried to get them in that way also). When I print my context I can see these classes in the bean list, and for what I know my packages hierarchy is correct, so what can be the problem?

**EDIT**
Ok, I got the suggestion from the duplicate question and I changed my main class code as follows:
**Main Application class:**

```
package it.mysite;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MailSenderApplication {

    @Autowired MySendService mySendService;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(MailSenderApplication.class, args);

        System.out.println("*****");
        for (String name : context.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
        System.out.println("*****");
        new MailSenderApplication().boot();
    }

    private void boot(){
        mySendService.sendReport();
    }
}
```

But I got the same error. Wasn't that the suggestion?

Comment: You're still doing the same mistake: using new to create Spring beans. Don't. Get the Spring bean from the Spring `context`. Or better, use a runner: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner

Comment: OMG thank you. This pointed me in the right direction. If you write your comment as an answer I'll chose that as the correct one.

Comment: @esseara You can't write it as an answer because the question has been closed as a duplicate. Essentially it's the same problem (meaning you can't use the `new` keyword that way). You can go to the other question though and vote for the most useful answer over there.